# How to deal correctly with android intent-filter?

Tags: android, google-chrome, react-native, android-intent, intentfilter

I'm trying to handle a Slack authentication in my react native application. After the Slack authentication success I want to redirect the user back to the application from the browser.

Everything works well on IOS with safari. I configured URL settings in the .plist file but on Android I have some difficulties to correctly set up the intent-filter. I think my problem comes from my MainActivity.java file but I'm not sure.

Here my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.willofeedback">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="willofeedback" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here my MainActivity.java file:

```
package com.willofeedback;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "willofeedback";
    }

    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
            return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I try to go to `intent://#Intent;scheme=willofeedback;package=com.willofeedback;end;`nothing happen and it behaves like a classic google search. What I expect is a redirection ask to the application like on safari on IOS.

When I run this following command in my terminal it works well and the application is opening:

`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "willofeedback://" com.willofeedback`

If anyone could help me, it would be so cool!
Thanks to the developer community!

**UPDATE**

It works on version 22 so I suspect the way to do that changed!

Comment: Can you show the react-native code?

Comment: I don’t think it comes from my js code, if I correctly understand you can call an app from browser like on safari if you enter whatsapp://app it will open whatsapp. It works well on IOS for me. It comes from the project configuration I guess